# Sum cells in column U place into Merged cells in Col Q, based on a values in Column A

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Set cell = Range("A2")
Do While cell.Value <> ""
    Set cell2 = cell.Offset(1)
    Do While cell2.Value = cell.Value
        Set cell2 = cell2.Offset(1)
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    cell.Offset(0, 15).Resize(cell2.Row - cell.Row).Merge
    cell.Offset(0, 15).Formula = "=+RC[4]"
    cell.Offset(0, 16).Resize(cell2.Row - cell.Row).Merge
    cell.Offset(0, 17).Resize(cell2.Row - cell.Row).Merge
    cell.Offset(0, 18).Resize(cell2.Row - cell.Row).Merge
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set cell = cell2
Loop
```

This code merges cells for me based on a ref # in col a.  I would like to add to it so in col Q I get the sum from the corresponding rows in col u

Thanks

[image: sample picture]

Comment: the sum of 'what' into column Q? you can also record a macro and see how it is written and adopt the code into yours.

Comment: in this sample I would want to sum u2 to u9 and put in q2, u10 to u15 in q10 and then u16 into q16

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use offset - I would first recommend setting up your worksheet as a variable. If you have multiple sheets open at a time Excel can get confused if you aren't specifically referring to that sheet - so running the macro can end up running it on an unintended sheet with irreversible results.

So if I were you I would set it up so I had the usual wb = ThisWorkbook, then set your range up I guess the same, I again would rather just loop through a range and do a check if blank, exit statement. But if you like doing it that way ok.

Just put in a loop statement in there to sum the columns before the one in question. Return that column by using cell.Column, and then you can loop from the previous column by creating a new range based on that column and however many rows you need (that wasn't really clear from your question).

```
Set r = range(cells(1,column-1), cells(xxx, column-1))
temp = 0
For Each item In r
    temp = temp + item
Next
```

Then set your new item equal to that temp.

Hopefully that's what you meant?

---

I would just set my range first, and workbook.

```
wb = ThisWorkBook
sh = "Sheet1" <-- whatever your sheet name is
```

I don't understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but in your main loop just add a loop instead of the insert formula statement (which I assume is your current try at a sum) and use a temp variable (temp = 0), which will then just add the current value of each row in the range you need. So as you said to someone else U2-U9, etc. Just make another range for the specific set of cells being merged.

Comment: Sorry, someone from here wrote that code for me, my skills go a little bit more than recording and basic changes, that doesnt make much sense to me

Comment: i am trying to add a line like this    
        cell.Offset(0, 16).Formula = "=sum(U" & cell2.Row & ":U" & cell.Row

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
cell.Offset(0, 16).Formula = "=sum(U" & cell.Row & ":U" & cell2.Row - 1 & ")"
```